# A regular expression in BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I need to find element with 'random' id in html. 
My code is look like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.find(id="id_123456_name")
```

`123456` - may changes every time, so I find [this](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression), but I cant understand, how use it.

I try:

```
soup.find(id="id_%s_name" % (re.compile("\d+")) )
```

But nothing find. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the *whole* value a regular expression object:

```
soup.find(id=re.compile("id_\d+_name"))
```

In your version, you are still looking for a literal string, not a regular expression, because you converted the regular expression object into a string instead. The literal string has a very strange value:

```
>>> import re
>>> "id_%s_name" % (re.compile("\d+"))
'id_<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x10f111750>_name'
```

This value of course is never found in your HTML document.